# getSystemClipboard failed on headless exception

Tags: java, clipboard

I'm trying to copy text to clipboard in java web based application using getSystemClipboard:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
```

But I got `java.awt.HeadlessException` exception and I don't understand why, especially because [according the doc](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/csg-old/java/jdk6docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html) this exception is related to calling IO HW that missing (and I have keyboard/mouse and not calling them).

What should I do to get system clipboard correctly?

### Edit

Thanks to your comments and Roshana Pitigala answer I understood my mistake: actually the Java application is running on the DC and not in the user local environment. Therefore get user system clipboard will get the DC clipboard (and not the user). the solution need to be in client side (that running in the customer environment).

Comment: Maybe you are running in [headless mode](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/08/what-is-headless-mode-in-java/), even if you have keyboard/display/mouse. Just check it with `GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()`

Comment: @Benoit, thank you, `isHeadless` return true. Does I have a workaround? I'm assuming I can't change this setting in my company project...

Comment: There is the (headless) server running java, and the web client (browser). To copy the clipboard in the browser you are moving on client-side JavaScript.

Comment: It may seem obvious but it already happened to me... I was running some java program via a remote shell, on a server. In this case of course your are always running in headless mode, unless you export the display to your desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running your application with VM parameter,

```
-Djava.awt.headless=false
```

Or add the following line before getting the clipboard.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't adding parameters do the project. there is a workaround?

Comment: Are you using any IDE? How do you run your project?

Comment: yes, eclipse, but I'm just one employee of ~1400... I can't change project settings

Comment: @AsfK I've edited my answer. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: actually I already tried it and it's not working for me, but now I understand my fault. will edit my Q